# Naming of subprocesses

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ps

This may be a silly question but, is there a way when using the python multiprocessing module, to edit the process name associated with the spawned subprocess?

The intended use for this would be to be able to use the command line utilities `top` or `ps` to check which subprocesses are still running and may have hung. E.g. say I have a script called MyScript.py which starts n subprocesses, then using top it would be desirable to see the processes:

```
MyScript.py
MyScript.py <tag1>
Myscript.py <tag2>
...
Myscript.py <tagn>
```

rather than just

```
MyScript.py
MyScript.py
MyScript.py
...
MyScript.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Python has no control over the process names that appear in the output of the "top" command. That is managed by the OS.

If you're using the `multiprocessing.Process` class, the process ID is available in the [PID](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.pid) attribute of the object, so you can print that out and cross-reference it with the output of top. Or you could have your program call top with the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module and filter the output to provide you with a only the relevant output.

Comment: For sure I can have the main keeping track of its threads as well as reporting them upon a client request, but for once I was hoping for an easy way out. Well, well  thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

What you *could* do (although it seems a bit hacky) is to start your processes via [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "myscript.py", "-tag", "tag1"])
```

Then you would need to adapt your `__main__` to branch into the right function when seeing the `-tag` argument. This may seem as overkill, as on Linux a subprocess is just a `fork()` and does not interpret the python file anew etc., but on Windows that's how multiprocessing works.

Comment: I thought about this but the problem then would be passing memory between the subprocess and the main process so not really an option in this case